# RKObjectMapping transform object before POST/PUT

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have successfully mapped JSON responses from Parse to my Core Data entity, `Message`, which has a to-one relationship with `Conversation` entity. When POSTing to Parse, relationships should have the format:

```
{
  "conversation": {
    "className": "Conversation",
    "objectId": "MK2GbaBseP",
    "__type": "Pointer"
  }
}
```

Therefore I need to serialise the `Conversation` entity in Core Data to this custom JSON. Is there a way that I can add in these extra fields as part of the RestKit serialisation process?

```
RKObjectMapping *messageRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
... some custom serialisation code
[manager addRequestDescriptor:[RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping: messageRequestMapping objectClass:PPSMessage.class rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodAny]];
```

I have tried creating an `RKValueTransformer` subclass for converting nested objects, but it doesn't appear to be being called.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of possible approaches:

1) create a custom class that describes the format, you pass it the object and it returns a dictionary during mapping which contains all of the required information.
In a number of ways this is best because parse.com layers on top of simply posting the object and that is what this models.

2) add methods to your managed object class which you can then add to the mapping and supply the required information.

3) just create a dictionary to pass to RestKit (limitations on the path that can be automatically determined so requires alternate routing config).

4) give up and use the parse supplied SDK.

Comment: Thanks, Wain. I went with option 2.